# How do I list the top 20 lines of a huge XML file?

Tags: xml, r, large-files

I am trying to parse a huge XML file using xmlEventParse and the branch argument.
For demostration, we will consider mtcars.xml to be huge.

```
fileName = system.file("exampleData", "mtcars.xml", package = "XML")
doc <- xmlParse(fileName, useInternalNode=TRUE)
doc
```

I can see the whole file this way but imagine the xmlParse crashes...

For further coding - it would be great to be able to see the beginning of the huge file. 
How can I see the first 20 lines of the XML file? (something like)

head(doc,20)

scan gives an error like this

```
> scan(fileName,nlines = 10)
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '<?xml'
```

in fact seeing the tail in some similar way would also be great or a random 20 lines from the middle of the file

Comment: Have you tried [readLines](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html)?

Comment: Would it also crash if you read parts, something like xmlRoot(doc)[1:9]? Would stick closer to the xml structure. Otherwise of course arvi1000's and Davids answers are correct, therefore +1 each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to display the first 20 lines of `fileName`, then use `readLines(...)`.

If you want to display the first 20 *elements* of the xml structure, you can use the handler functions in `xmlEventParse(...)`

```
f <- function(ctxt,name,attrs,.state) {
  if (name=="record") {
    print(paste(.state, attrs, sep=" - "))
    .state = .state+1
    if(.state>20) xmlStopParser(ctxt)
  }
  .state
}
class(f) = "XMLParserContextFunction"  
xmlEventParse(fileName,handlers=list(.startElement=f),
              useTagName=FALSE, addContext = FALSE, state=0)
# [1] "0 - Mazda RX4"
# [1] "1 - Mazda RX4 Wag"
# [1] "2 - Datsun 710"
# [1] "3 - Hornet 4 Drive"
# [1] "4 - Hornet Sportabout"
# [1] "5 - Valiant"
# [1] "6 - Duster 360"
# [1] "7 - Merc 240D"
```

The handler `f(...)` in this example displays the attributes of the first 20 `<record>...</record>` nodes and then stops processing the xml file. `state` is a special variable that allows passing state information to the handlers. There are other examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try readLines().

```
first20lines <- readLines(fileName, n=20)
```